# Printing Coq definition without loading library

Tags: ocaml, coq

Coq is using a module system similar to OCaml. In OCaml, we can apply a function like Module_A.Module_B.Func and use Module_A.Module_B. to find the path to Func.

However, I cannot do similar things in Coq. For instance, if I just run `Print Coq.Arith.Minus.minus_n_O.` Coq reports `Coq.Arith.Minus.minus_n_O is not a defined object.`

I must first load the library and then can print the object. In the following case, it is successful.

```
From Coq Require Export Arith.Minus.
Print Coq.Arith.Minus.minus_n_O.
```

Is there a way to run `Print Coq.Arith.Minus.minus_n_O` without loading the library just as applying a function in OCaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Coq there is a distinction between requiring and importing a module. `Require` is the keyword that lets you load the library while `Import` lets you drop the prefix. `Export M` does `Import M` but also says that when the current module is itself imported, then `M` will be imported too.

I would say what you want is

```
From Coq Require Arith.Minus.
Print Coq.Arith.Minus.minus_n_O.
```

without the `Export`.

To compare with ocaml, `Import` is like `open` and `Require` is just implicit in ocaml: a module is imported when it is used basically.

You can find more in [the documentation of Import](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/modules.html#coq:cmd.Import), [Export](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/modules.html#coq:cmd.Export) and [Require](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.From-%E2%80%A6-Require). Also in general to find more about commands, just look up the [command index](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/coq-cmdindex.html).

Comment: Thanks most sincerely!